# rxtools fails under osx Lion and HomeBrew

Tags: rviz, rxtools, macos, homebrew, macos-lion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm following the tutorial reported [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew) in order to install ROS on my MacBook pro with Lion.

I succeed in the installation of the basic stacks but now I'm blocked with Rviz. When I try to rosmake it the compilation of rxtools fails with the following error:

```
 -- Build files have been written to: /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/rx/rxtools/build
  cd build && make -l8
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Scanning dependencies of target rxtools
  [  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/topic_display.o
  [ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/topic_display_generated.o
  [ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/topic_display_dialog.o
  [ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_generated.o
  [ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_panel.o
  [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_filter.o
  [ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_text_filter.o
  [ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_text_filter_control.o
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_severity_filter.o
  [ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_severity_filter_control.o
  [ 61%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_list_control.o
  [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/rosout_setup_dialog.o
  /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_setup_dialog.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void rxtools::RosoutSetupDialog::onTopicBrowse(wxCommandEvent&)’:
  /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rosout_setup_dialog.cpp:74: warning: ‘__s_getDataType’ is deprecated (declared at /Users/luca/Software/ros/electric/ros_comm/messages/rosgraph_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:86)
  [ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/logger_level_panel.o
  [ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/src/rxtools/init_roscpp.o
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/librxtools.dylib
  ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "wxRichTextCtrl::wxRichTextCtrl(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxValidator const&, wxString const&)", referenced from:
        rxtools::TextboxDialog::TextboxDialog(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long)in rosout_generated.o
    "wxRichTextBuffer::BeginBold()", referenced from:
        rxtools::RosoutListControl::onItemActivated(wxListEvent&)       in rosout_list_control.o
    "wxRichTextBuffer::BeginTextColour(wxColour const&)", referenced from:
        rxtools::RosoutListControl::onItemActivated(wxListEvent&)       in rosout_list_control.o
    "wxRichTextCtrl::ms_classInfo", referenced from:
        rxtools::TextboxDialog::onChar(wxKeyEvent&)      in rosout_list_control.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../lib/librxtools.dylib] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rxtools.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12323/rxtools-fails-under-osx-lion-and-homebrew/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably due to you using the incorrect version of wxWindows and wxPython.  There is a note in the tutorial on how to fix this:

```
rosmake --rosdep-install rviz
```

This does a binary install of wxWindows and wxPython to be used with both rxtools and rviz.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-19**:
@mjcarroll Actually it worked. I removed the file '$PREFIX/share/ros/wxpython-version.installed' and then executed 'rosdep install rviz'. Thanks!

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-12-19**:
It may also be worthwhile to rebuild all of ROS, as it looks like you have an architecture mismatch somewhere. Especially after removing the files that macports left behind.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-12-19**:
You won't see it in brew list due to the way that it is installed.  However, you should see it in $PREFIX/share/ros/wxpython-version.installed, where prefix is your brew prefix (`brew --prefix`).  Also, you can test the wxPython install with the python shell using: `import wx; wx.version()`

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2011-12-18**:
@mjcarroll Thanks. Hi did it before but it doesn't work. Should I see wxPython and wxWindows in the list of the brew packages (`brew list`)? Cause I don't see them. Is it possible that I have some old files from macPorts?